# Ubuntu Server SD on HP Microserver G8 G1610T

Tags: 12.04, hp

I've recently purchased a HP Microserver G8 G16010T with the Intel Celeron processor.  Have installed 2 x 2TB seagate NAS drives and 4Gb RAM.  I'm primarily looking to get a LAMP setup going.
Would really appreciate responses to these questions as I'm feeling my way here:

1. HP list as a certified OS: Ubuntu Server 12.04, and point to 
   http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-server-amd64.iso - just want to be sure though that this is the correct version for the G1610T (i.e. not just the G2020)?
2. I've read many of the HP forum entries on the fan noise on the HP MS G8 - and appear to be linked to either iLo or the B120i Smart Array controller - but understand that these features aren't supported by Ubunutu Server?  Is that correct or are their successful work-arounds?
3. I want to run Ubuntu Server on a microSD - booting a SANDISK 32GB extreme SD card in the internal SD slot (i.e. not one of the hard drives) - has anybody had any experience setting this up and any hints/tips (or detailed instructions:))?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is kind of correct, that this is an certified version. But as you pointed out, point 2 is the real problem. The certification just says 'it runs'. It doesn't tell you anything about how well it runs (see ubuntu certification 1255330 for this).
2. The terrible truth is, that ubuntu doesn't runs well on this machine. I will switch to another OS while the noise is really uncool. So take this advice: if the sound volume is a relevant factor for you: switch the os or the hardware. Otherwise see the [link](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-Netservers/MicroServer-Gen8-is-noisy/td-p/6171563/page/9) (but there is no quick and easy solution so far. I am really annoyed about my decision buying this machine and trusting in the certification. :( The bug tickets for the [smart array driver](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/214703#comment-46) (the whole family seems to be unsupported for now) could be relevant for you.
3. See steffs answer for point 3. :-)

I hope this information could help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. YES, MicroServer G8 is certified to run Ubuntu 12.04
2. The fan noise is related to the thermal sensor for the HDDs. In order to do not face the problem you have to use the RAID controller embedded in the server, but it is not supported by HP. Upgrading iLO and BIOS both to the latest firmware, reduces the speed and the noise. Running Windows and using the embedded RAID is very quiet.
3. Yes I am running Ubuntu installed on a 16 GB uSD card since past October and it is just fine. Be sure to upgrade to the latest firmware both the iLO and the BIOS, it is MANDATORY. Ubuntu booting from uSD is certified by HP.

Regards